# Rebuilding iText7 nuget with Debug configuration

Tags: c#, itext7

I am in the process of porting a complex set of reports from iText5 to iText7 and need to rebuild the .Net community edition with Debug symbols to complete the port from 5 to 7. I am able to run the "possibly" correct CLI command this way:

```
dotnet pack iTextCore.netstandard.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
```

but that doesn't get me the same package structure you build for the official nuget package.

We will of course pay for the commercial license when we know our code runs, but in the meantime I'm trying to convert old code.

What is the official guidance from iText Software on how developers should accomplish the port from 5 to 7 with your existing resources? Is there a way to get a Debug build with symbols.

Best regards and congrats on building an excellent library.

Answer (score 0):

**TL; DR**: use [this](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) repository and run

```
dotnet build iTextCore.netstandard.with.svg.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
nuget pack itext7.nuspec
```

---

There is no official guidance on how to migrate from iText5 from iText7. This is a major update of the library and almost all of the user-facing code was developed from scratch. Coming up with such a guide is absolutely infeasible because there is too much to cover. One source of information would be to compare samples from `iText in Action` book which covered a lot of use cases for iText5 library to their versions ported to iText7. The latter ones can be found [here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/book/browse). But if you have specific questions feel free to post them on StackOverflow and you will probably get your answers (if those questions haven't been answered yet; many have been already).

The way the official NuGet package is assembled is more difficult than the one you guessed, but only a tiny bit.

If you look at the repository layout, you will find [itext7.nuspec](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext7.nuspec) file which is a complete descriptor of the final package. To pack everything you need to call

```
nuget pack itext7.nuspec
```

However, you need to build the binaries to pack first. You are interested in [iTextCore.netstandard.with.svg.sln](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/iTextCore.netstandard.with.svg.sln) solution file which integrates all the Core modules at the moment. The command would be similar to what you described:

```
dotnet build iTextCore.netstandard.with.svg.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Please note, however, that an easier approach in order to enable debugging might be for you to download the source code and reference the projects directly, thus you would be easily able to walk through the source code, possibly do the modifications etc.